# Why does linter error with "An argument for 'thisArg' was not provided"?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to use spread syntax in this code :

```
Math.min.apply( ...categories.map( cat => cat.category_id ) );
```

which shows the following lint error:

> An argument for 'thisArg' was not provided

How to use spread syntax on a function that returns an array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` takes context and the arguments in array. So use this,

```
Math.min.apply(null, categories.map( cat => cat.category_id ) ));
```

But as `apply` doesnt use the context (see implementation [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L105)), you should simply use,

```
Math.min(...categories.map( cat => cat.category_id ) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use apply.

```
Math.min(...categories.map(c => c.category_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. `Function.apply` does except a `this` argument first. For example:

```
Math.min.apply(Math, ...categories.map(cat => cat.category_id));
```

The question here is to know if you actually needs to use apply or not.

All in all this is just a ''syntax'' error.